# Stuck on The Key to Redemption - Find the Archon

Tags: darksiders-2

In Darksiders 2, I'm trying to do the quest *The Key to Redemption*. I'm at the Crystal Spire and unable to go any further from the second floor. I have defeated the 2 corrupt angels and can't seem to utilize that yellow explosive sphere correctly. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

#### You need to use the Soul Splitter.

The issue here is that the shadowbomb needs to be carried across a gap, which Death can't do by himself.  Split Death's soul midway between the shadowbomb and the Corruption crystals, have one copy of Death run to the shadowbomb and pick it up, then with the other copy on the other side of the gap, throw the shadowbomb so that the other copy catches it.  Then switch to the other copy of Death, move towards the Corruption crystals, and blast it apart.

**Edit:** I dug out an old save file from [my private SVN repository of saves](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10690908#10690908) (*edit: now a Git repository*) in order to replay the segment in question, so that I can provide some screenshots.

*Click on an image to view it in full size.*

[image: Picking up the shadowbomb]
[image: Relaying the shadowbomb]
[image: Clearing the Corruption crystals using the shadowbomb]